# Link to specific PowerPoint Slide in a library

Tags: hyperlink, office, powerpoint-services

I want to create links at a Sharepoint page that open a presentation at a specific slides.
The presentation is hosted at Sharepoint and I can save it in any format (pptx, ppsx, html, .. ), so no restrictions here.

**Edit**
Maybe it is more a PowerPoint issue. Therefore I posted a more [generic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829968/html-link-to-specific-powerpoint-slide) at StackOverflow and will update my question here.

Answer (score 3):

Since SharePoint uses the PowerPoint web viewer/editor to show PowerPoints, you can't use the "#4". That will only work in a file-system.

You need to use the URL query string. The string you're looking for is: “&wdSlideID=###” where ### is the ID of your slide.

You can find the ID by vieweing your PowerPoint in SharePoint and skipping to the slide you want. I have a full description of how to do this on my blog:

http://lmunck.com/2014/06/embed-specific-powerpoint-slide-in-sharepoint-2013-page/

Comment: It did not work for me because I was not able to find the “&wdSlideID=###” string. With PowerPoint 2013 when you click on the slide show view there is no way to see the URL because the slide show opens in full screen and you can't see the address bar.
With the slide show in the browser view, the URL does not have the “&wdSlideID=###” string.

Comment: See my answer elsewhere. The given parameter of wdSlideID may work for a particular formulation of the URL, as indicated in the linked blog post; however, this is not the typical URL format. For the typical format, try this:

https://sharepointsite.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/Documents/mypowerpoint.pptx&action=default&DefaultItemOpen=1&wdSlideIndex=3

Note that the correct parameter appears to be wdSlideIndex. I've tried this in SharePoint 2013 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

lmunck's solution got me most of the way there, but I had the same problem as Lava--the Slide Show view opens full screen and you can't see the wdSlideId.  I was able to find the correct link by doing the following:

1. Open the presentation from the SharePoint library in PowerPoint Online.
2. Click the ellipsis menu item and choose Embed.
3. In the Embed pop-up window, use the arrows to navigate the preview to the slide to which you want to link.
4. Click the Open in New Window button (icon on the right).

The URL in the address bar of this new window will contain the URL including the wdSlideId.  Use this URL for a link directly to the desired slide.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer suggests using a query string parameter of wdSlideId, but this doesn't work for the typical URL format of the PowerPoint viewer. I've found that the correct parameter is wdSlideIndex. This is documented here: https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/318gp4/linking_to_specific_powerpoint_slide_on_sharepoint/

So, for example: https://sharepointsite.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/Documents/mypowerpoint.pptx&action=default&DefaultItemOpen=1&wdSlideIndex=3

I've tried it on SharePont 2013 and it works. I doubt you will find this information anywhere else. Odd, really. Very hard to find.

Answer (score -2):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1242) on StackOverflow ... I believe it answers the question.

EDIT: so others can see what didn't work:

Link to http://www.whatever.com/hello.ppt#4 for slide 4 to be opened initially.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's the solution I found,too. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Well back to the drawing board ... I will also follow up later if I have time to see about a better solution.

Comment: It's academic but, for future reference, while  this is a reasonable answer to the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: No worries ....